# Show or hide custom fields by user's role [frontend]

Tags: custom-field

Is it possible to hide or show custom fields by user's role.

For example:
I have custom field "wholesale_notice" and it have to be visible only for my "wholesale" user role.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to hide or show custom fields by user's role. 
Use current_user_can() for finding current user role. This function returns true if current user has capability or role. For example your current user is "wholesale" then you can use like this:

```
<?php if( current_user_can('wholesale')) {  ?> 
    // stuff here for wholesale
<?php } ?>
```

For more reference check this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can